# The application is in break mode. The type initializer for 'RESTAURANT_POS.ModConnection' threw an exception

Tags: vb.net

Am getting this error when i run my apllication.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll  Additional information: The type initializer for 'RESTAURANT_POS.ModConnection' threw an exception.

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports Microsoft.Win32

'''Module ModConnection
Public DBServerHost As String
Public DBPort As String
Public DBUsername As String
Public DBPassword As String
Public DBDatabase As String
Public query As String
Public dr As MySqlDataReader
Public da As New MySqlDataAdapter
Public cm As New MySqlCommand
Public cn As New MySqlConnection
Public adodbcn As ADODB.Connection
Public adodbrs As ADODB.Recordset
Public Username As String
Public Password As String
Public RememberMe As String
Public MyDate As DateTime = DateString
Public Status As String
Public ImageIsNull As String
Public AutoAccountID As String
Public AID As String
Public Gender As String
Public MyID As String
Public RemarkofSelectImage As String
Public DateFull As String

```
Public Sub ConnectToMySQL()
    adodbcn = New ADODB.Connection
    adodbcn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" & "SERVER=" & DBServerHost & ";" _
        & "DATABASE=" & DBDatabase & ";" & "USER=" & DBUsername & ";" & "PASSWORD=" & DBPassword & ";" & "PORT=" & DBPort & ";"
    adodbcn.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    adodbcn.Open()
End Sub

Public Sub DisconnectFromMySQL()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    If adodbcn.State = 1 Then
        adodbcn.Close()
        adodbcn = Nothing
    End If
    rs = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub ConnectToDatabase()
    Try
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.ConnectionString = "Database=" & DBDatabase & "; Server=" & DBServerHost &
                "; user id=" & DBUsername & "; Password=" & DBPassword & "; Port=" & DBPort & "; Max Pool Size=100;"
            cn.Open()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to connect to the database", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Database Configuration Failed!")
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub DisconnectFromDatabase()
    Try
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal rQuery As String) As MySqlDataReader
    Call ConnectToDatabase()
    cm.Connection = cn
    cm.CommandText = rQuery
    da.SelectCommand = cm
    dr = cm.ExecuteReader
    Return dr
End Function

Public Sub main()
    Call GetData()
    frmLogin.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Public Sub GetData()
    Dim RegKey As RegistryKey
    On Error GoTo ErrTrap
    RegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\" & Application.CompanyName)
    DBServerHost = RegKey.GetValue("MySQLServer")
    DBUsername = RegKey.GetValue("MySQLUsername")
    DBPassword = RegKey.GetValue("MySQLPassword")
    DBPort = RegKey.GetValue("MySQLPort")
    DBDatabase = RegKey.GetValue("MySQLSchema")
    Call ConnectToDatabase()
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        GoTo ErrTrap
    End If
    Exit Sub
```

errtrap:
RegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", True)
RegKey.CreateSubKey(Application.CompanyName)
End Sub

```
Function MaxAccountID() As String
    ExecuteQuery("select ifnull(max(userid)+367,1221) as AID from tbluser")
    With dr
        While dr.Read
            If .HasRows = True Then
                AutoAccountID = CInt(.Item("AID").ToString)
            End If
        End While
    End With
    Call DisconnectFromDatabase()
    Return AutoAccountID
End Function
```

End Module'''

Comment: Public MyDate As DateTime = DateString can cause this exception when the string cannot be converted.

Comment: Thank you very much Hans Passant. That's where my problem was. Which is best way to declare date?

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the source code file and now the compiler will tell you the best way.